# Cache keys from java library are not visible in the Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

Sprint Boot App - OrderApp has the following dependencies

- Java Library (Exchange Rates uses caffiene caching library to cache country symbols)
- Java Library (Crypto Currencies uses caffiene caching library to cache crypto symbols)

Java libraries are built using `id 'java'` under plugins section

OrderApp uses org.springframework.cache.CacheManager, but since the java libraries were not wrapped using CacheManager the keys cached using the dependent libraries aren't seen in the OrderApp.

If I have to AutoWired org.springframework.cache.CacheManager interface in the java library then I would have to convert this into a Spring Boot App itself. How should I handle this so that cache keys are visible.

This is how its used in the library

```
public class CacheManager<K, V> {

    private final Cache<K, V> cache;

    public CacheManager(long maxSize, long expireAfterWriteSeconds) {
        cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(maxSize)
            .expireAfterWrite(expireAfterWriteSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        cache.put(key, value);
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return cache.getIfPresent(key);
    }

}
```

Comment: Create your own `CacheManager` that wraps the other ones (or use reflection to get the Caffeine caches and integrate that in the `CaffeineCacheManager`.

Comment: These are internal libraries hence we would like to use the same CacheManager across libraries and application and we want the keys used in the library to be refleced from within the App

Comment: And where do I state you shouldn't do that? You need to modify the app to have the proper caches loaded from those libraries.

Comment: The CacheManager in the Spring Boot App is AutoWired, but the internal libraries its based on the attached code, so the keys are not visible within the App

Comment: It doesn't matter if the `CacheManager` is autowired. Create an explicit configuration for it so you can retrieve the existing caches from thel ibraries and add it to the `CacheManager`. If you really don't want to do that write a `BeanPostProcessor` for the `CaffeineCacheManager` which rips out the caches (with reflection) from the libraries and registers them with the `CaffeineCacheManager`. Also if you are using the libraries, the caching should be transparante anyway, so why would you need them in your own cachemanager? As the libraries do their own caching.

Comment: In order to debug the cached key/value pairs in the library, we really need to have them exposed via the CacheManager interface in the Spring Boot App. All of them use Caffiene by the way

Comment: I give up. I gave you the solution 3 times already (rip out the cache and add them to the `CaffeineCacheManager`)...

Comment: Can you get the instance the library creates? You could put that in a BeanFactory, so that you will get that if you autowire it.

Comment: Just create beans for `Exchange Rates` and `Crypto Currencies`, then register their caches with the help of `CaffeineCacheManager.registerCustomCache(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you did something wrong. I was able to make it working.

Steps that I took to make it working are as follows:

I've created a java library with the name **cache-test** which will have the cache logic.

I'm using **Gradle with Groovy**, **JDK 17** and **Caffeine 2.5.5**

Project Structure:

[image]

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.5.5'
}
```

CacheManager.java:

```
package com.example.cachetest;

import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache;
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CacheManager<K, V> {

    private final Cache<K, V> cache;

    public CacheManager(long maxSize, long expireAfterWriteSeconds) {
        cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(maxSize)
                .expireAfterWrite(expireAfterWriteSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        cache.put(key, value);
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return cache.getIfPresent(key);
    }

}
```

Now, I have generated a jar with the name `cache-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` via gradle.

Now, I've created another project with the name **cache-test-client** to test the cache logic.

I have added the cache-test jar as a dependency in my client project.

I'm using **Spring Boot 3.1.4**, **JDK 17**, **Gradle with Groovy** in the client project.

Project Structure:

[image]

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.5.5'
    implementation files('src/main/resources/cache-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

CacheTestClientApplication.java:

```
package com.example.cachetestclient;

import com.example.cachetest.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CacheTestClientApplication {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager<String, String> cacheManager() {
        return new CacheManager<>(10, 30);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CacheTestClientApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Note:** You have to explicitly create a bean of your custom `CacheManager` from java library into your app's Spring Container to make the things working for you.

**Also, Point to be Noted:** You can't use **Spring based CacheManager** and assume that this will pick your java library CacheManager magically in the OrderApp. So, kindly stick to the **CacheManager** that is present in the java library.

Resource.java (Sample Endpoint for testing):

```
package com.example.cachetestclient;


import com.example.cachetest.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Resource {

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;


    @GetMapping("cache-put/{value}")
    public String testCaching(@PathVariable String value) {
        cacheManager.put("abc", value);
        return value + " is saved in lib cache.";
    }

    @GetMapping("cache-get/{value}")
    public String get(@PathVariable String value) {
      return cacheManager.get("abc") + " is retrieved from lib cache.";
    }

}
```

Now, the application starts successfully.

Output:

http://localhost:8080/cache-put/Anish

[image]

http://localhost:8080/cache-get/Anish

[image]

This tells that cache is keeping all the values intact.